# openapi-generator does not generate JsonNullable<?> for Java Client

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, nullable, openapi-generator

The [openapi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) should generate JsonNullable<?> type when a property is defined as nullable:true.

I've created the next repository to show the issue: https://github.com/robertop87/opengen

Basically when property defined in swagger.yml has nullable: true, like the next example:

openapi-generator version 7.3.0 ([gradle plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin))

```
tag:
  type: string
  nullable: true
```

The generator should generate Java code as:

`private JsonNullable<String> tag = JsonNullable.undefined();`

But the current result is:

`private String tag;`

Please take a look in the example repository, maybe I'm doing something wrong or missing something.

Additionally I already reported this issue here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/17873

I removed the nullable property, also make a combination with required, in any case I got the expected result.

My generator configuration in gradle.build file is:

```
tasks.register('generateClient', GenerateTask) {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set(swaggerFile.toString())
    outputDir.set(swaggerOutputDir)
    configOptions.set([dateLibrary: "java8", useJakartaEe: "true"])
}
```

**Update 1:**

The JsonNullable is being generated properly using

```
  generatorName.set("spring")
```

But this is to generate a server application, not a client.

**Update 2:**
According docs there are extension to enable the expected generator behavior, in this case enabling `x-is-jackson-optional-nullable: true` should be enough, but the generator still doing the same.

Check latest commits in https://github.com/robertop87/opengen

**Update 3:**

When debugging the openapi-generatod source code, I noticed that JsonNullable is working fine, because the generator's library is configured as [WEBCLIENT](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/436a3e0744a2ce8208a7c3b8116fca6e7195143a/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/java/org/openapitools/codegen/java/JavaClientCodegenTest.java#L1917).

Additional note: **x-is-jackson-optional-nullable** was not needed in the configuration.

So I configured my generator like this:

```
tasks.register('generateClient', GenerateTask) {
    generatorName.set("java")
    library.set("webclient") // only with webclient the JsonNullable is generated properly
    inputSpec.set(swaggerFile.toString())
    outputDir.set(swaggerOutputDir)
    configOptions.set([
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            useJakartaEe: "true",
            openApiNullable: "true" // This is enabled by default
    ])
}
```

As result the JsonNullable were generated properly.

But, I'll test a bit more in client side if it's working as expected.

Comment: The issue is isolated, the models are not being generated properly for 2 specific library configurations. Check here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/17919